# What is wrong with my Javascript Math code?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a slider for a number game. if you roll above 50 you will get *2 of the amount bet. The slider allows you to choose how much to bet.

Problem 1: However when the user wins, the score does not add. It shows 05 , 055, 0555, instead of 5, 10 ,15. 
Problem 2: The amount bet also does not correspond to the slider. It just adds 50 or -50.

```js
var amountBet = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
var originalNumber = 0;

function generateNumber() {
  var randomNum = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2);
  var pass = 52.5;

  if (randomNum > pass) {

    var el = document.getElementById('number');
    el.textContent = originalNumber += (amountBet);
    msg = 'You won! ';

  } else {

    var el = document.getElementById('number');
    el.textContent = originalNumber -= (amountBet);
    msg = ' You lost! ';

  }

  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Roll Above " + x + " to win";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Roll Above:</div>

<input type="range" id="myRange" min="0" max="100">
<!-- Slider that should select amount bet -->

<div onclick="myFunction()">Click to see amount</div>
<!-- Click to see amount selected on slider -->

<button onclick="generateNumber()" type="submit" value="Roll" id="button1" class="button button">Roll above 52.99 for *2</button>
<!-- Button to roll -->

<p id="number">0</p>
<!-- Amount of credits user has -->
```

Comment: You need to convert the string to a number before you can add to it. `amountBet` is almost definitely a string, not a number.

Comment: Strongly recommend using consistent and any of the several "normal" code indentation and bracing styles, at least when asking for help.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: No "almost" :-)

Comment: Note that `.toFixed(2)` produces a **string**, so it's not just `amountBet`, but also `randomNum`, that's a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I couldn't remember if some elements had numeric values or  not. A slider presumably only deals with numbers, so it's conceivable that it returns a number directly. Been awhile since I've written JS

Comment: @Carcigenicate: :-) The `value` of an `input` is still always a string, even with the new HTML5 controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `amountBet` into the function, because you get otherwise the default value of the slider and take the numerical value of the slider.

Then move `el` outside of the comparison, because it is the same in both cases.

Later make the winner/loser text viewable.

```js
var amountBet;
var originalNumber = 0;

function generateNumber() {
    var randomNum = Math.random() * 100;
    var pass = 52.5;
    var el = document.getElementById('number');
    amountBet = +document.getElementById("myRange").value;
    if (randomNum > pass) {
        originalNumber += amountBet;
        el.textContent = originalNumber + ' ' + 'You won! ';
    } else {
        originalNumber -= amountBet;
        el.textContent = originalNumber + ' ' + 'You lost! ';
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Roll Above " + x + " to win";
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Roll Above:</div>
<input type="range" id="myRange" min="0" max="100">
<div onclick="myFunction()">Click to see amount</div>
<button onclick="generateNumber()" type="submit" value="Roll" id="button1" class="button button">Roll above 52.99 for *2</button>
<p id="number">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line of code after you get the string value in your first line of code, using the Number javascript function.

```
var amountBet =document.getElementById("myRange").value;    
var finalBetAmount = Number(amountBet);
```

Comment: We don't know that there aren't fractional bets allowed. Separately, it's much more useful to say *why* they want to do that, and why they were getting what they were getting.

Comment: What about `randomNum`?

Comment: That is true. OP, are there fractional bets allowed?  Either way you will have to convert the string representation to a numeric one. @kaien

Comment: Pretty sure it does, the OP have `var pass = 52.5;` in his code. i would use `var finalBetAmount = Number(amountBet)`

Comment: Updated to account for the possibility of a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

causes for the problem:

problem 1 => You are concatenating a string and a number. The value from input field will be in string format.

problem 2=> The default value of the slider is taken every time as the value from the input control is not read inside the function.

Solution:

- Convert the string value from range selector to `Number`.
- Convert the string value from `toFixed(2)`  to `Number`. (The toFixed function produces a string output).
- Get the slider value inside the function.

Debugged Code :

```
var amountBet; 
var originalNumber =0;
function generateNumber() {
    amountBet =Number(document.getElementById("myRange").value);
    var randomNum = Number((Math.random()*100).toFixed(2));
    var pass = 52.5;    
    if ( randomNum > pass ) 
    {
          var res = originalNumber+=amountBet;
          var el = document.getElementById('number');
          el.textContent= res;
          msg = 'You won! '; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        var el = document.getElementById('number');
        var res = originalNumber-=amountBet;
        el.textContent= res;
        msg = ' You lost! ';
    }
}
```